# Redis on message listener triggered twice

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm working on chat application using NodeJS and Redis , why  i'm using Redis subscribe , because i need to notify other users when i user logged in , my problem start when the user logged for the first time it works fine the on message listener called for one time , but when the same user refresh the page , i found that the publish method has been called twice.

Here's sample of my code that i use:

```js
var redisClient = redis.createClient({
  auth_pass: password
});
var myServer;

myServer = require('http').createServer(app);

var socketIo = require('socket.io').listen(myServer);
myServer.listen(port);

redisClient.subscribe('myChannel');

socketIo.on('connection', function(dbSocket) {
      var redisClient2 = redis.createClient({
        auth_pass: password
      });

      /***Code for handle request***/

    }

    redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
      //When refresh page , and I call publish method , the system enter message listener twice

      var data = JSON.parse(message);
    });
```

Comment: Flagging this question because  it's unclear what you're asking
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I update my question , may be that helps you to identify my problem, @bitoiu aslo could you please remove the vote down on my question , and thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide an actionable piece of code so we can help you. You are describing an extremely broad scenario. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @bitoiu here's sample of code that i use , hope that help you to find my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your redisClient.on('message') event is set inside the callback of on connection, therefore every time a connection is made, you attach the event again.

Move this code block outside of the on('connection') event should solve the issue.

```
redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
      //When refresh page , and I call publish method , the system enter message listener twice

      var data = JSON.parse(message);
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Regarding redisClient.on('message') will only trigger if a publish event occur